# NSScrollView with NSTextView calls drawRect too many times

Tags: drawrect, nsscrollview

In a NSDocument-based application, each text document is displayed in a NSTextView enclosed in a NSClipView which is itself enclosed in a NSScrollView.

• case 1: When I load a text whose height is smaller than the scroll view frame, after the text is displayed, the drawRect method of the NSTextView keeps being called a few times per second, even when nothing happens on screen and when the keyboard or mouse is not used. But In Xcode the displayed CPU usage returns to 0% after a few seconds and energy use is negligible.

• case 2: When the loaded text is too big to be entirely displayed in the frame, the scrollview's drawRect method is called dozens of times per second and CPU usage stabilises about 80 to 90% (with high energy impact) even after several minutes with no user interaction with the computer and the application!

Then with this long text, once the user has scrolled down to the end of it, the behaviour returns to the first case (no CPU use, negligible Energy impact, a few drawRect calls per second), whatever the cursor position is.

As I understood that drawRect is called only when some changes occurred in the view or its subviews, I wonder why the calls are so numerous when the application is in standby, with such an impact on CPU Use. I profiled in Instruments, and the CPU usage is very high with more than 99% of it associated to the drawRect method.

This is both very intriguing and a serious problem of performance for my application. I precise that I never call any drawRect method myself (nor use setNeedsDisplay).

The App is developed with Xcode 13.2.1 running on Monterey 12.0.1 - and compiled after 10.14 Kit

Comment: Is `drawRect` called each time the cursor blinks? How do you check, is the CPU usage caused by logging? Any subclasses and overrides? How big is the big text? What are the settings of the text view (non-contiguous layout, spell check, data detectors etc.)?

Comment: Case 2: See [NSScrollView - Overdraw](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html) "To facilitate Responsive Scrolling, your document view will be asked to draw portions that are not currently visible to the user. AppKit balances the amount of non-visible content drawn with the amount of memory and power usage such drawing requires. NSScrollView is then free to visually scroll to any previously overdrawn content during Responsive Scrolling.".

Comment: To answer your questions, in case 2, the call is much more frequent than the cursor blink. This trouble occurs as soon as the length is greater than the frame capacity. In my tests, the capacity is about 1500 characters, and the long texts are between 2000 and 4000. I will check the settings.

Comment: Concerning the overdraw, if I constrain it in my NSTextView subclass like this:
- (void)prepareContentInRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [super prepareContentInRect:[self visibleRect]];
}
the method is called just once before the first drawRect call but not after if there's no user action…

Comment: Spellchecking is enabled. But if I deactivate it, the behaviour keeps the same. The same for myTextView.automaticDataDetectionEnabled.

Comment: In allowing non-contiguous layout, the calls to drawRect stop! But unfortunately, after scrolling back and forth in the text, I get an error message, then a crash:
"The window has been marked as needing another Display Window pass, but it has already had more Display Window passes than there are views in the window"

Comment: I forgot to mention a very important fact of my design: the NSScrollView that holds the NSTextView is enclosed as the main view of a NSSplitView, as I can open a secondary view sometimes linked to a user action. With the big texts, opening this panel crashes the app (same message as in my last comment), and will small ones, there is no problem

Comment: Have you tried the big text in TextEdit?

Comment: Yes. No problem. And the when the application runs on Mojave, I have no problem with it…